# How do you make a bridge between two connections?

Tags: 11.04, network-bridge

I've done this:

- Created a wireless network via the network manager.
- I have internet through a wire.

I want create a wireless network and share my internet access that I get from a wire.
@TheX told me that I have to bridge the two connections but I don't know how to.

the setup I want is this:

- Sharing connections through the wireless
- getting internet through a wire

@TheX gave me a [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge#Installing%20bridge-utils) that might work.

I need to connect eth0 with wlan0

Has anyone got this to work in 11.10?

Comment: I heard love can do that but maybe squid might work better!

Comment: could you explain a bit more?

Comment: http://freshmeat.net/articles/configuring-a-transparent-proxywebcache-in-a-bridge-using-squid-and-ebtables if it works I would answer the question with your results

Comment: Will try this tomorrow, I'll get back to you...

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu Desktop, then it's _much_ easier than that since you can do it with Network Manager with just a few clicks.

Comment: no it's not LOL

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ubuntu Desktop, then it's really simple. Click the network icon at the to right of your screen. Select "Create new wireless network". Give the network a name, choose an encryption type (wep, wpa, etc) and make a password. Click "create" and that should be it. You can now connect to the wireless network from other computers and the wired connection should be shared with the wireless network you just created. :)

Comment: That's what's not working. Have you done this yourself?

Comment: yes, I did it after commenting on your question and before providing an answer. If it's not working, then you should provide som information about that. It's terribly difficult to guess and this is the first time you've mentioned that.

Comment: So when you created your network with a wire plugged in, did you try and connect to the wireless network with a mobile phone or so? to see if the network works. **You can't connect with your laptop to see if it works!**

Comment: I connected with both my mobile phone and another laptop. (I have several. I'm a geek :))

Comment: Yes you connected but could u use the internet??  Can you prove it in some way? I have tried what you are talking about like 10 times and it still wont work!

Comment: I can use the internet that way, yes.

Comment: good for you because no one else can.

Comment: I wonder what makes you want to become a liar over this.

Comment: Maybe it has something to-do with your network card. I've tried a million times but it **WONT** work...

Comment: I have to side with Alvar on this one.
This isn't really answering the question.

Comment: I do know, however, that the network won't show up on all phones. In that case, you'll have to specify the network name manually. My Nokia phones doesn't have these problems, but it seems to be the case with all Android-phones. But the steps I provided does work.

Comment: In any case, that's how it's _supposed_ to work so if it doesn't, then you should file a bug containing specific information about the equipment you use.