# How do I bridge my wireless to my wired connection?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, networking, internet, sharing

I want to bridge the wireless connection with the wired connection. The wireless is the host and the wired is the client, so to speak.

```
Internet sharing (inet <--> wifi <--> ethernet)
```

I tried to bridge my ethernet connection by going to

- network manager > edit connections
- wired > edit
- IPv4 settings > shared to other computers

[Screenshots](http://www.highqualityinternetcorn.com/?page=Article&id=6)

However, it seems to automatically disconnect half a second after it says "connection established"!

### edit 2

got the network manager logs, it seems the address is in use. See http://pastebin.com/DjqRshxW , line 45.

`nm-tool` output is here: http://pastebin.com/x5Aci5V1 .
I tried firestarter, as mentioned in another thread, and no luck.

I don't have time to bother with a dozen command line tricks, unless is copy & pasting a shell script... so please suggest ways that use GUIs and/or won't leave my computer in a confused state (e.g. disabling network manager, manually connecting to a WPA network, installing brutils, etc.).

**edit**: one idea that *would* work, if it's possible -- is there a way to share connections via SSH and SOCKS5? I'd need to do this at a system-wide level though; I only know how to do it through the browser now. Then, I could run `ifconfig eth0 192.168.4.1` on the computer sharing the inet, and `ifconfig eth0 192.168.4.2` on the computer I'm trying to share with; I know this does work for host-to-host transfers.

### edit 3

If I run `sudo killall dnsmasq`, then nothing is using the `10.42.43.1` address the network manager sharing wants to use. But now it just takes longer to die, with error "NetworkManager[5935]:  dnsmasq died with signal 9" [ http://pastebin.com/4FNtpugi ]. Looking at just the commands [ http://pastebin.com/1vrtQeWk ], maybe it's trying to route eth0 to itself? I'm not that familiar with networking things though.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/54375/how-do-you-make-a-bridge-between-two-connections

Comment: @Alvar, How so?

Comment: you are trying to bridge your wired connection with your wireless. that's the same problem I have...

Comment: @Alvar, no, I'm trying to share from wifi to ethernet. Hopefully the new title change makes that clear. Plz upvote so it gets attention, thx.

Comment: I only give up-votes to good or interesting question. IF YOU WANT MORE ATTENTION, **OFFER BOUNTY!** :)

Comment: Sorry I'm no longer interested in a solution. I'll mark anyone else's answer as correct if someone else verifies it. If you are running into this problem, I *highly* suggest dumping < $20 on a TP-LINK TL-WN722N USB Wifi adapter for the computer you're trying to bridge to, and forget the bridging. It's Atheros hardware, which works out of the box on Linux, and seems to be fine signal-strength. (I've gone through a lot of wifi adapter models before finding one that works. And, to go on, I'm using one of them as a Wifi access point, via hostapd....)

Comment: Accept my wiki answer. it's the answer you came up with and others may have use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest dumping < $20 on a `TP-LINK TL-WN722N USB Wifi adapter` for the computer you're trying to bridge to, and forget the bridging.

It's **Atheros** hardware, which works out of the box on Linux, and seems to be fine signal-strength.

I've gone through a lot of wifi adapter models before finding one that works. And, to go on, I'm using one of them as a Wifi access point, via `hostapd`.

Comment: I'm trying to bridge a NAS that is based on an Catalina SoC (which is based on PowerPC 32) and it runs a minimal distro of Linux for PowerPC called Thecus OS 6. Do you know if that wifi adapter would work on it? In other words: when you say "works out of the box on Linux" do you mean any Linux, or x86?

Answer (score 2):

There is a GUI application for creating bridges:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/bridger/

Comment: I t would probably be better if the link did not take you straight to the download but the page describing the program. http://sourceforge.net/projects/bridger/