# Share Wifi Connection with Android device

Tags: 11.10, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you make a bridge between two connections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54375/how-do-you-make-a-bridge-between-two-connections)

I have a Laptop with Ubuntu 11.10 connected via Wifi to internet. I would use the laptop as access point and let other devices like my android phone or another laptop to connect to internet THROUGH ubuntu.
Is there a step by step guide to make it possible?
Thanks in advance.